# Cross browser Javascript number precision

Tags: javascript, numbers

Within JavaScript, numbers are defined as 64bit double-precision. I have a specific use in mind for a distributed web application, which would only work if I can rely on consistent results across all browsers.

Despite the spec using the IEEE standard, I naturally have a suspicion that there may be tiny differences in implementations of the maths library or even the underlying hardware, which could cause compound errors.

Is there any source of compatibility data, or a reliable test suite to verify double precision calculations in the browser? In particular, I also need to consider mobile browsers (usually ARM based).

Clarification -

This is a question about browser compatibility.  I'm trying to understand whether all browsers can be relied upon to treat numbers in a reliable, consistent and repeatable way as defined for IEEE floating point.  In most languages this is a safe assumption, but it's interesting that there's a little uncertainty about this in the browser.

There's been some great advice on how to avoid floating point problems due to lack of precision and rounding errors.  In most cases, if you require accuracy you should follow this advice!

For this question, I'm not trying to avoid the problem but understand it.  Floating point numbers are inherently inaccurate by design, but as long as some care is taken with how builds are made that inaccuracy can be completely predictable and consistent. IEEE-754 describes this to a level of detail that only a standards body could.

I've decided to offer a small bounty if anyone can cite,

- Genuine compatibility data relating to the implementation of IEEE numbers in mainstream browsers.
- A test suite intended to verify the implementation within the browsers, including verifying the correct internal use of a 64 bit floating point number (53 bit mantissa).

In this question I'm not looking for alternative options, workarounds or ways to avoid the problem. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but have you considered using Strings instead? Math may be little more difficult, but then you'll never have to worry about precision.

Comment: @DannyKirchmeier - Math may be a _little_ more difficult?

Comment: @DannyKirchmeier: Using strings (I assume you mean things akin to Java's `BigDecimal`, or C#'s `decimal` type) can be useful for financial calculations, but that doesn't mean you don't have to worry about precision, just that you have *different* worries about precision. They can't (for instance) represent one-third precisely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - You can represent one-third precisely in a string: "1/3".

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes. See the assumption at the beginning of the comment.

Comment: Not an answer, so I'll just comment: A) One element in a test suite that's handy is `0.1 + 0.2`, which on a conforming implementation should yield `0.30000000000000004`. B) I wouldn't be surprised if there were a couple of implementations in the wild with the odd bug around an edge case.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Assuming you need only a small subset of operations, you shouldn't have to expend that much work. But "little" was probably a vast understatement.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I didn't event think about irrational numbers; All I was thinking of was financial situations. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: For something such as a financial system, using strings as a way to do  fixed point decimal is a good solution for consistent results. For this question, I'd like to know specifically about floating point as it's more of a physics problem.

Comment: Just a guess: The basic math itself should proove quite reliable even on partly emulating platforms. However there may be some surprises in JS library functions sourrounding it. So even if the CPU or the math lib does exact IEEE doubles, it may be hard always reliable get those numbers intact in and out of the JS float datatype as it usually passes a lot of code in the JS parser, the Number class, parseFloat or string append operations functions.

Comment: @dronus Your thought process is close to the one that created this question. If implementation correctly, an IEEE based number should be completely predictable, but is it implemented correctly? Do the browsers creators verify this, are release builds always with the correct flags, and is there a unit test to confirm this.  Still searching!

Comment: @leebriggs Well I liked to emphasize that the main problem may not be the IEEE implementation, but the higher level JS libraries around. So I would give a much higher risk to the application failing as whole even IF the browser would pass IEEE conformance test on the JS math operators level.

Comment: @dronus True. There are some know compatibility issues at the library level, particularly rounding errors (from memory). To be categorised as either "hazard to be avoided", or "damn, the whole blasted thing is caput".  I guess my focus is due to the fact that I have found some data on that (so far only hazards), but not the really low level question. (which would make it caput).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(EDIT: The bug mentioned below was closed as fixed on 3 Mar 2016. So my answer is now "maybe".)

Unfortunately the answer is no. There is at least one outstanding bug in v8 that, due to double-rounding, means it might not match IEEE 754 double precision on 32-bit Linux.

- [v8 bug entry](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=436)
- [Firefox bug entry - fixed in 2009](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264912)
- [More info on the double-rounding issue](http://www.vinc17.org/research/extended.en.html)

This can be tested with:

```
9007199254740994 + 0.99999 === 9007199254740994
```

I can verify that this fails (the left-hand side is `9007199254740996`) on Chrome 26.0.1410.63 running on 32-bit Ubuntu. It passes on Firefox 20.0 on the same system. At the very least, this test should be added to your test suite, and maybe test262.

Comment: After some delay I thought it fair to finally award this answer, as the v8 bug you referenced was the key problem I found in my own research.

Answer (score 20):

This is just for fun, as you already stated and I created a new answer because this one is in a different vein.  But I still feel like there are a few random passerby's who are ignoring the futility of the problem. So let's start by addressing your points:

Firstly:

> Genuine compatibility data relating to the implementation of IEEE
>   numbers in mainstream browsers.

doesn't exist, and for that matter doesn't even make any sense, [IEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE) is just a standards body...? I am not sure if this vague on purpose or on accident, I will assume you were trying to say IEEE 754, but there in lies the rub... there are technically 2 versions of this standard [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE754) AND [IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).  Basically the former is newer and addresses the latter's oversights.  Any sane person would assume that any maintained JavaScript implementation would update to the latest and greatest standard, but any sane person should know JavaScript better than that, and even if JavaScript wasn't crazy, there is no specification saying that the implementation has to be/stay up to date ([check the ECMA spec yourself if you don't believe me](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), they don't even talk "versions"). To compound the matters further the IEEE Standard 754-2008 for Floating-Point Arithmetic supports two
encoding formats: the decimal encoding format, and the binary encoding format.  Which as would be expected are compatible with each other in the sense that you can go back and forth without loss of data, but that's assuming we have access to the binary representation of the number, *which we don't* (without attaching a debugger and looking at the store the old school way)

However, from what I can tell it seems it is general practice to "back" a JavaScript `Number` with an old fashioned `double` which of course means that we are at the mercy of the compiler used to actually build the browser.  But even in that realm, we can't and shouldn't be assuming equality even if all the compilers were on the same version of the standard (they aren't) and even if all the compilers implemented the standard in its entirety (they don't).  Here's an excerpt from [this paper](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf), which I have deemed an interesting, worthwhile and relevant-to-this-dialog read...

> Many programmers like to believe that they can understand the behavior
>   of a program and prove that it will work correctly without reference
>   to the compiler that compiles it or the computer that runs it. In many
>   ways, supporting this belief is a worthwhile goal for the designers of
>   computer systems and programming languages. Unfortunately, when it
>   comes to floating-point arithmetic, the goal is virtually impossible
>   to achieve. The authors of the IEEE standards knew that, and they
>   didn't attempt to achieve it. As a result, despite nearly universal
>   conformance to (most of) the IEEE 754 standard throughout the computer
>   industry, programmers of portable software must continue to cope with
>   unpredictable floating-point arithmetic.

While finding that I also found this [reference implementation done completely in JavaScript](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) (note: I haven't actually verified the validity of the implementation).

**All that said, let's move on to your second request:**

> A test suite intended to verify the implementation within the
>   browsers, including verifying the correct internal use of a 64 bit
>   floating point number (53 bit mantissa).

Since JavaScript is an interpreted platform you should see now that there is no way to test the set of *script + compiler (VM/engine) + compiler that compiled the compiler + machine* in an absolute and reliable way from the point of JavaScript.  So unless you want to build a test suite that acts as a browser host and actually "peeks" into the private memory of the process to ensure a valid representation, which would be fruitless most likely anyway since the number are most likely "backed" by a `double` and that is going to conform as it does in the C or C++ that browser was built in. There is no absolute way to do this from JavaScript since all we have access to is the "object" and even when we view the `Number` in a console we are looking at a `.toString` version.  For that matter I would posit that this is the only form that matters since it will be determined from the binary and would only become a point of failure if  for the statement: `n1 === n2 && n1.toString() !== n2.toString()` you could find an `n1, n2` that is relevant...

That said, we can test the string version and in reality it is just as good as testing the binary as long as we keep a few oddities in mind. Especially since nothing outside the JavaScript engine/VM ever touches the binary version.  However this puts you at the mercy of an oddly specific, possibly very finicky and poised to be changed point of failure. Just for reference, here is an excerpt from [webkit's JavaScriptCore's Number Prototype (NumberPrototype.cpp)](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/NumberPrototype.cpp) displaying the complexity of the conversion:

```
    // The largest finite floating point number is 1.mantissa * 2^(0x7fe-0x3ff).
    // Since 2^N in binary is a one bit followed by N zero bits. 1 * 2^3ff requires
    // at most 1024 characters to the left of a decimal point, in base 2 (1025 if
    // we include a minus sign). For the fraction, a value with an exponent of 0
    // has up to 52 bits to the right of the decimal point. Each decrement of the
    // exponent down to a minimum of -0x3fe adds an additional digit to the length
    // of the fraction. As such the maximum fraction size is 1075 (1076 including
    // a point). We pick a buffer size such that can simply place the point in the
    // center of the buffer, and are guaranteed to have enough space in each direction
    // fo any number of digits an IEEE number may require to represent.
    typedef char RadixBuffer[2180];

    // Mapping from integers 0..35 to digit identifying this value, for radix 2..36.
    static const char* const radixDigits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    static char* toStringWithRadix(RadixBuffer& buffer, double number, unsigned radix)
    {
        ASSERT(isfinite(number));
        ASSERT(radix >= 2 && radix <= 36);

        // Position the decimal point at the center of the string, set
        // the startOfResultString pointer to point at the decimal point.
        char* decimalPoint = buffer + sizeof(buffer) / 2;
        char* startOfResultString = decimalPoint;

        // Extract the sign.
        bool isNegative = number < 0;
        if (signbit(number))
            number = -number;
        double integerPart = floor(number);

        // We use this to test for odd values in odd radix bases.
        // Where the base is even, (e.g. 10), to determine whether a value is even we need only
        // consider the least significant digit. For example, 124 in base 10 is even, because '4'
        // is even. if the radix is odd, then the radix raised to an integer power is also odd.
        // E.g. in base 5, 124 represents (1 * 125 + 2 * 25 + 4 * 5). Since each digit in the value
        // is multiplied by an odd number, the result is even if the sum of all digits is even.
        //
        // For the integer portion of the result, we only need test whether the integer value is
        // even or odd. For each digit of the fraction added, we should invert our idea of whether
        // the number is odd if the new digit is odd.
        //
        // Also initialize digit to this value; for even radix values we only need track whether
        // the last individual digit was odd.
        bool integerPartIsOdd = integerPart <= static_cast<double>(0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFull) && static_cast<int64_t>(integerPart) & 1;
        ASSERT(integerPartIsOdd == static_cast<bool>(fmod(integerPart, 2)));
        bool isOddInOddRadix = integerPartIsOdd;
        uint32_t digit = integerPartIsOdd;

        // Check if the value has a fractional part to convert.
        double fractionPart = number - integerPart;
        if (fractionPart) {
            // Write the decimal point now.
            *decimalPoint = '.';

            // Higher precision representation of the fractional part.
            Uint16WithFraction fraction(fractionPart);

            bool needsRoundingUp = false;
            char* endOfResultString = decimalPoint + 1;

            // Calculate the delta from the current number to the next & previous possible IEEE numbers.
            double nextNumber = nextafter(number, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
            double lastNumber = nextafter(number, -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
            ASSERT(isfinite(nextNumber) && !signbit(nextNumber));
            ASSERT(isfinite(lastNumber) && !signbit(lastNumber));
            double deltaNextDouble = nextNumber - number;
            double deltaLastDouble = number - lastNumber;
            ASSERT(isfinite(deltaNextDouble) && !signbit(deltaNextDouble));
            ASSERT(isfinite(deltaLastDouble) && !signbit(deltaLastDouble));

            // We track the delta from the current value to the next, to track how many digits of the
            // fraction we need to write. For example, if the value we are converting is precisely
            // 1.2345, so far we have written the digits "1.23" to a string leaving a remainder of
            // 0.45, and we want to determine whether we can round off, or whether we need to keep
            // appending digits ('4'). We can stop adding digits provided that then next possible
            // lower IEEE value is further from 1.23 than the remainder we'd be rounding off (0.45),
            // which is to say, less than 1.2255. Put another way, the delta between the prior
            // possible value and this number must be more than 2x the remainder we'd be rounding off
            // (or more simply half the delta between numbers must be greater than the remainder).
            //
            // Similarly we need track the delta to the next possible value, to dertermine whether
            // to round up. In almost all cases (other than at exponent boundaries) the deltas to
            // prior and subsequent values are identical, so we don't need track then separately.
            if (deltaNextDouble != deltaLastDouble) {
                // Since the deltas are different track them separately. Pre-multiply by 0.5.
                Uint16WithFraction halfDeltaNext(deltaNextDouble, 1);
                Uint16WithFraction halfDeltaLast(deltaLastDouble, 1);

                while (true) {
                    // examine the remainder to determine whether we should be considering rounding
                    // up or down. If remainder is precisely 0.5 rounding is to even.
                    int dComparePoint5 = fraction.comparePoint5();
                    if (dComparePoint5 > 0 || (!dComparePoint5 && (radix & 1 ? isOddInOddRadix : digit & 1))) {
                        // Check for rounding up; are we closer to the value we'd round off to than
                        // the next IEEE value would be?
                        if (fraction.sumGreaterThanOne(halfDeltaNext)) {
                            needsRoundingUp = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Check for rounding down; are we closer to the value we'd round off to than
                        // the prior IEEE value would be?
                        if (fraction < halfDeltaLast)
                            break;
                    }

                    ASSERT(endOfResultString < (buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1));
                    // Write a digit to the string.
                    fraction *= radix;
                    digit = fraction.floorAndSubtract();
                    *endOfResultString++ = radixDigits[digit];
                    // Keep track whether the portion written is currently even, if the radix is odd.
                    if (digit & 1)
                        isOddInOddRadix = !isOddInOddRadix;

                    // Shift the fractions by radix.
                    halfDeltaNext *= radix;
                    halfDeltaLast *= radix;
                }
            } else {
                // This code is identical to that above, except since deltaNextDouble != deltaLastDouble
                // we don't need to track these two values separately.
                Uint16WithFraction halfDelta(deltaNextDouble, 1);

                while (true) {
                    int dComparePoint5 = fraction.comparePoint5();
                    if (dComparePoint5 > 0 || (!dComparePoint5 && (radix & 1 ? isOddInOddRadix : digit & 1))) {
                        if (fraction.sumGreaterThanOne(halfDelta)) {
                            needsRoundingUp = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (fraction < halfDelta)
                        break;

                    ASSERT(endOfResultString < (buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1));
                    fraction *= radix;
                    digit = fraction.floorAndSubtract();
                    if (digit & 1)
                        isOddInOddRadix = !isOddInOddRadix;
                    *endOfResultString++ = radixDigits[digit];

                    halfDelta *= radix;
                }
            }

            // Check if the fraction needs rounding off (flag set in the loop writing digits, above).
            if (needsRoundingUp) {
                // Whilst the last digit is the maximum in the current radix, remove it.
                // e.g. rounding up the last digit in "12.3999" is the same as rounding up the
                // last digit in "12.3" - both round up to "12.4".
                while (endOfResultString[-1] == radixDigits[radix - 1])
                    --endOfResultString;

                // Radix digits are sequential in ascii/unicode, except for '9' and 'a'.
                // E.g. the first 'if' case handles rounding 67.89 to 67.8a in base 16.
                // The 'else if' case handles rounding of all other digits.
                if (endOfResultString[-1] == '9')
                    endOfResultString[-1] = 'a';
                else if (endOfResultString[-1] != '.')
                    ++endOfResultString[-1];
                else {
                    // One other possibility - there may be no digits to round up in the fraction
                    // (or all may be been rounded off already), in which case we may need to
                    // round into the integer portion of the number. Remove the decimal point.
                    --endOfResultString;
                    // In order to get here there must have been a non-zero fraction, in which case
                    // there must be at least one bit of the value's mantissa not in use in the
                    // integer part of the number. As such, adding to the integer part should not
                    // be able to lose precision.
                    ASSERT((integerPart + 1) - integerPart == 1);
                    ++integerPart;
                }
            } else {
                // We only need to check for trailing zeros if the value does not get rounded up.
                while (endOfResultString[-1] == '0')
                    --endOfResultString;
            }

            *endOfResultString = '\0';
            ASSERT(endOfResultString < buffer + sizeof(buffer));
        } else
            *decimalPoint = '\0';

        BigInteger units(integerPart);

        // Always loop at least once, to emit at least '0'.
        do {
            ASSERT(buffer < startOfResultString);

            // Read a single digit and write it to the front of the string.
            // Divide by radix to remove one digit from the value.
            digit = units.divide(radix);
            *--startOfResultString = radixDigits[digit];
        } while (!!units);

        // If the number is negative, prepend '-'.
        if (isNegative)
            *--startOfResultString = '-';
        ASSERT(buffer <= startOfResultString);

        return startOfResultString;
    }
```

... as you can see, the number here is backed by a traditional `double` and the conversion is anything but simple and straightforward. So what I devised was this: since I conjecture that the only spot that these implementations will differ are their "rendering" to strings. I built a test generator that is three fold:

1. tests the "string result" against a reference string result
2. tests their parsed equivalents (ignoring any epsilon, I mean exact!)
3. tests a special version of the strings that solely adjusts for the rounding "interpretation"

To accomplish this we need access to a reference build, my first thought was to use one from a native language but with that I found that the numbers produced seemed to have a higher precision than JavaScript in general leading to far more errors. So then I thought, what if I just used an implementation already inside a JavaScript engine. WebKit/JavaScriptCore seemed like a really good choice but it would have also been a lot of work to get the reference build up and running so I opted for the simplicity of .NET since it has access to "jScript" while not ideal seemed upon initial examination to produce closer results than the native counterpart.  I didn't really want to code in jScript since the language is all but deprecated so I opted for C# bootstrapping jScript through a `CodeDomProvider`.... After a little tinkering here's what it produced: http://jsbin.com/afiqil **(finally demo sauce!!!!1!)**, so now you can run it in all browsers and compile your own data, which upon my personal inspection it seems string rounding interpretation varies in EVERY browser I tried, however I've yet to find a major browser that handled the numbers behind the scenes (other that the stringify-ing) differently...

now for the C# sauce:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace DoubleFloatJs
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            private static string preamble = @"

    var successes = [];
    var failures = [];

    function fpu_test_add(v1, v2) {
        return '' + (v1 + v2);  
    }

    function fpu_test_sub(v1, v2) {
        return '' + (v1 - v2);
    }

    function fpu_test_mul(v1, v2) {
        return '' + (v1 * v2);
    }

    function fpu_test_div(v1, v2) {
        return '' + (v1 / v2);
    }

    function format(name, result1, result2, result3, received, expected) {
        return '<span style=""display:inline-block;width:350px;"">' + name + '</span>' +
            '<span style=""display:inline-block;width:60px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold; color:' + (result1 ? 'green;"">OK' : 'red;"">NO') + '</span>' + 
            '<span style=""display:inline-block;width:60px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold; color:' + (result2 ? 'green;"">OK' : 'red;"">NO') + '</span>' + 
            '<span style=""display:inline-block;width:60px;text-align:center;font-weight:bold; color:' + (result3 ? 'green;"">OK' : 'red;"">NO') + '</span>' + 
            '<span style=""display:inline-block;width:200px;vertical-align:top;"">' + received + '<br />' + expected + '</span>';
    }

    function check_ignore_round(received, expected) {
        return received.length > 8 &&
            received.length == expected.length && 
            received.substr(0, received.length - 1) === expected.substr(0, expected.length - 1);
    }

    function check_parse_parity_no_epsilon(received, expected) {
        return parseFloat(received) === parseFloat(expected);
    }

    function fpu_test_result(v1, v2, textFn, received, expected) {
        var result = expected === received,
            resultNoRound = check_ignore_round(received, expected),
            resultParse = check_parse_parity_no_epsilon(received, expected),
            resDiv = document.createElement('div');

        resDiv.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
        resDiv.style.fontFamily = 'Courier New, Courier, monospace';
        resDiv.style.fontSize = '0.74em';
        resDiv.style.background = result ? '#aaffaa' : '#ffaaaa';
        resDiv.style.borderBottom = 'solid 1px #696969';
        resDiv.style.padding = '2px';

        resDiv.innerHTML = format(textFn + '(' + v1 + ', ' + v2 + ')', result, resultNoRound, resultParse, received, expected);

        document.body.appendChild(resDiv);
        (result ? successes : failures).push(resDiv);
        return resDiv;
    }

    function fpu_test_run(v1, v2, addRes, subRes, mulRes, divRes) {
        var i, res, 
            fnLst = [fpu_test_add, fpu_test_sub, fpu_test_mul, fpu_test_div],
            fnNam = ['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'div'];

        for (i = 0; i < fnLst.length; i++) {
            res = fnLst[i].call(null, v1, v2);
            fpu_test_result(v1, v2, fnNam[i], res, arguments[i + 2]);
        }
    }

    function setDisplay(s, f) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < successes.length; i++) {
            successes[i].style.display = s;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < failures.length; i++) {
            failures[i].style.display = f;
        }
    }

    var test_header = fpu_test_result('value1', 'value2', 'func', 'received', 'expected'),
        test_header_cols = test_header.getElementsByTagName('span');

    test_header_cols[1].innerHTML = 'string';
    test_header_cols[2].innerHTML = 'rounded';
    test_header_cols[3].innerHTML = 'parsed';
    test_header.style.background = '#aaaaff';

    failures.length = successes.length = 0;

    ";

            private static string summation = @"

    var bs = document.createElement('button');
    var bf = document.createElement('button');
    var ba = document.createElement('button');

    bs.innerHTML = 'show successes (' + successes.length + ')';
    bf.innerHTML = 'show failures (' + failures.length + ')';
    ba.innerHTML = 'show all (' + (successes.length + failures.length) + ')';

    ba.style.width = bs.style.width = bf.style.width = '200px';
    ba.style.margin = bs.style.margin = bf.style.margin = '4px';
    ba.style.padding = bs.style.padding = bf.style.padding = '4px';

    bs.onclick = function() { setDisplay('block', 'none'); };
    bf.onclick = function() { setDisplay('none', 'block'); };
    ba.onclick = function() { setDisplay('block', 'block'); };

    document.body.insertBefore(bs, test_header);
    document.body.insertBefore(bf, test_header);
    document.body.insertBefore(ba, test_header);
    document.body.style.minWidth = '700px';

    ";

            private void buttonGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var numberOfTests = this.numericNumOfTests.Value;
                var strb = new StringBuilder(preamble);
                var rand = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++)
                {
                    double v1 = rand.NextDouble();
                    double v2 = rand.NextDouble();

                    strb.Append("fpu_test_run(")
                        .Append(v1)
                        .Append(", ")
                        .Append(v2)
                        .Append(", '")
                        .Append(JsEval("" + v1 + '+' + v2))
                        .Append("', '")
                        .Append(JsEval("" + v1 + '-' + v2))
                        .Append("', '")
                        .Append(JsEval("" + v1 + '*' + v2))
                        .Append("', '")
                        .Append(JsEval("" + v1 + '/' + v2))
                        .Append("');")
                        .AppendLine();
                }

                strb.Append(summation);

                this.textboxOutput.Text = strb.ToString();
                Clipboard.SetText(this.textboxOutput.Text);
            }

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Type evalType = CodeDomProvider
                    .CreateProvider("JScript")
                    .CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters(), "package e{class v{public static function e(e:String):String{return eval(e);}}}")
                    .CompiledAssembly
                    .GetType("e.v");

                this.JsEval = s => (string)evalType.GetMethod("e").Invoke(null, new[] { s });
            }

            private readonly Func<string, string> JsEval;

        }
    }
```

or a pre-compiled version if you should choose: http://uploading.com/files/ad4a85md/DoubleFloatJs.exe/ **this is an executable, download at your own risk**

[image: screen shot of test generator application]

I should mention that the purpose of the program is just to produce a JavaScript file in a text box and copy it to the clipboard for convenience for pasting wherever you choose, you could easily turn this around and put it on an asp.net server and add reporting to results to ping the server and keep track in some massive database... which is what I would do to it if I desired the information..

...and, ...I'm, ...spent I hope this helps you -ck

Comment: Very good! I would like to take all the points every awarded to everyone who ever said "in jQuery you can...." and give them all to you.  This is a research question, the bounty is going to go to whoever provides the best data towards a conclusion.  We'll see where that is at the end of the bounty, but for the moment I commend this response for up votes.

Comment: Part of this question came from solving the same sort of problem in C where it was sometimes necessary to verify the fpu compiler options at run time. As you say, much easier with binary access, but there are still some options.  Try in the console (1e154 * 1e154) / 1e154, then again as (1e155 * 1e155) / 1e155.  That was one of my first trivial checks to see if any browsers were using 80-bit precision.

Answer (score 9):

Summarizing everything below, you can expect compliance on the majority of systems save for a few IE's glitches, but ought to use a sanity check as a precaution (proposition is included).

- [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (both rev. 3 and 5) is very precise on IEEE 754's peculiarities such as conversions, rounding mode, overflow/underflow and even signed zeros (sec. 5.2, 8.5, 9.*, 11.5.*, 11.8.5; 15.7 and 15.8 deal with floats too). It doesn't just "leave things to the underlying implementation". There are no apparent differences between vv. 3 and 5 and [all major browsers support v.3 at least](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Dialects). So its rules *are* honored by everyone, at least nominally. Let's see...

  - No browser passes [test262 ECMAScript compliance tests](http://test262.ecmascript.org/) completely ([WP#Conformance tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Conformance_tests)). However, no test262 errors [found on google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ecma%20test262%20detailed%20results&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en:official&client=firefox) are float-related.
  - IE5.5+ ([[MS-ES3]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) reports discrepancies in `Number.toFixed`, `Number.toExponential`, `Number.toPrecision`. Other differences aren't float-related. I couldn't run test262 in IE8;
  - FF uses special types for number and mandatory conversion fns between them and C types (see e.g. [JSAPI user guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSAPI_User_Guide)) which suggests that things are in fact not handed down to C. Test on FF10 didn't show any float-related errors;
  - Opera users [did report float-related errors half a year ago](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2011/09/13/es5?startidx=250);
  - Webkit's test262 failures [don't appear to be float-related](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65579).

To validate a system, you can use float-related tests from test262. They are located at `http://test262.ecmascript.org/json/ch<2-digit # of spec chapter>.json`; test code can be extracted with (python 2.6+):

```
ch="05";  #substitute chapter #
import urllib,json,base64
j=json.load(urllib.urlopen("http://test262.ecmascript.org/json/ch%s.json"%ch))
tt=j['testsCollection']['tests']
f=open('ch%s.js'%ch,'w')
for t in tt:
  print >>f
  print >>f,base64.b64decode(t['code'])
f.close()
```

Another opportunity is [IEEE 754 compliance tests in C](http://cant.ua.ac.be/old/ieeecc754.html).

Relevant sections from test262 (ones that compare floating point numbers) are as follows:

```
{
"S11": "5.1.A4: T1-T8",
"S15": {
    "7": "3: 2.A1 & 3.A1",
    "8": {
        "1": "1-8: A1",
        "2": {
            "4": "A4 & A5",
            "5": "A: 3,6,7,10-13,15,17-19",
            "7": "A6 & A7",
            "13": "A24",
            "16": "A6 & A7",
            "17": "A6",
            "18": "A6"
        }
    }
},
"S8": "5.A2: 1 & 2"
}
```

this list and the concatenated source of all the relevant test files (as of 3/9/2012, no files from the harness) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/U6nX6sKL

Comment: Thank you, that's really useful.  In particular, I'll be poking around inside some parts of test262.

Comment: this will probably be definitive when and if test262 is ever finished, but as of right now the test is incomplete and does very little in the realm of floating point precision consistency validation, here are all the sections (as of 3/9/2012) that compare floating point numbers included in the test and their source http://pastebin.com/U6nX6sKL as you can see the only consistency validation is in the realm of trigonometric functions along with `Math.pow` and `Math.sqrt` checks... I'll edit the relevant sections into the community answer above

Comment: How are you gonna test "precision consistency"? You cannot check the rounding of every possible result on the number axis in a reasonable time. A few math fns look fine for me as a sanity check. They do validate the precision and rounding mode used - assuming the same ones are used in all other cases.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev there are only 2 tests in ALL of test262 (that I am aware of) that have anything to do with precision, and NEITHER check anything about the "rounding" mode, they are: [ 8.5_A2.1 - Number type represented as the double precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 **AND** 8.5_A2.2 - Number type represented as the extended precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 ]. Furthermore who said anything about "reasonable time" test262 can take 30 minutes to run on a slow machine and no one ever said anything about doing this "online" only *compiling data* has ever been mentioned, so if you happen...

Comment: `ch15/15.8/15.8.2/15.8.2.16/S15.8.2.16_A7.js`, calculated `sin` values are compared with reference ones. If precision is low, large discrepancy will occur (I just checked this in C). If rounding mode is different, the last meaningful digit wouldn't match. `ch15/15.8/15.8.2/15.8.2.16/S15.8.2.16_A6.js`, `sin` is checked to be periodic up to 100 periods. If net rounding error is greater than the reference 3e-12 , we'll see it too.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I listed those chapters/sections above, they are checking that each of the trig function's output conforms, for all you know they are implemented as a look up table and there are no actual "operations" that are taking place, their description doesn't reflect any intention to check anything other than the output periodicity and accuracy. They are under the test section titled "The Math Object" which should give you an indication of their purpose.

Comment: @ckozl Please be respectful to other users. Using the expression "STFU" is in no way acceptable.

Comment: @ckozl: Yes, they have another purpose. Checking floating point arithmetics to some extent is a side-effect which IMO is enough for the check I proposed. I consider the original question answered.

Comment: I've no desire to argue any longer. IMO that's enough for the problem at hand and that is my answer. BTW I was offended but not very surprised. This is far from the first time I piss others off with my self-confidence and calculating 3 steps ahead on-the-fly and not telling it 'cuz it's obvious/too long to explain/can be reconstructed from previous data. And let's close this topic - it's far longer than needed already.

Answer (score 6):

General rule of thumb is that when number precision is important and you only have access to floating point precision numbers, all of your calculations should be done as integer math to best ensure validity (where you're assured 15 digits of assuredly valid data).  And yes there are a bunch of general numeric idiosyncrasies in JavaScript but they are more associated with the lack of precision within floating point numbers and not with UA implementations of the standard.  Look around for the pitfalls of floating point math, they're numerous and treacherous.

I feel as I should elaborate a little, for instance I wrote a program (in JavaScript) that used basic calculus to determine the area of polygon with dimensions given in meters or feet.  Instead of doing the calculations as is, the program converted everything to micrometers and did its calculations there as everything would be more integral.

hope this helps -ck

---

***In response to your clarification, comments and concerns***

I'm not going to repeat my comments below in their entirety, however the short answer is no one will ever be able to say that [**EVERY IMPLEMENTATION**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers) is 100% on 100% of devices. Period. I can say and others will tell you the same, is that on the ***current major browsers*** I have not seen nor heard of any browser specific detrimental bug involving floating point numbers.  But your question itself is kind of a double edged sword since **you want to "rely" upon "unreliable" results**, or simply that you want all the browsers to be **"consistently inconsistent"** - in other words instead of trying make sure a lion will play fetch, your time would be better spent looking for a dog, meaning: **you can rely 110% on integer math *AND the results of said math*, the same goes for string math which has already been suggested to you...**

good luck -ck

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help me, but the advice is valid for others when precision is a problem.

Comment: For me, floating point is the correct choice. My problem concerns consistency and whether all browsers treat floating point numbers in a reliable manner.

Comment: @leebriggs since there is an almost endless number of UAs out there it is all but impossible to say that this is consistent across all of them. what i will say it the implementation is very consistent across all the major browsers currently in use. As a matter if fact in all my time I can't say that I've run into a UA specific floating point number bug. -ck

Comment: @ckozl Hardly any applications rely on exact float point results, experience counts for nothing if you haven't actually tested float point consistency.

Comment: @eBusiness try `1.9 * 3` or `2.1 * 3` in a console, and that is only a single decimal place and an integer... as i said it is ***impossible*** to test floating point consistency across ***ALL*** browsers, so experience counts for everything. if you have experience otherwise and would like to share, i am all ears... all big boy math programs either use 128bit precision or integer math... rather than try to assure the same ***ticks*** and ***idiosyncrasies*** it's easier just to remove them

Comment: @ckozi The implementation of 64bit precision floating point is remarkably consistent and in many other situations/languages its quite common to rely on it as a predictable format.  In multiplayer gaming for example, each client may simulate the environment in lock step as part of a peer to peer architecture.

Comment: @ckozi "as i said it is impossible to test floating point consistency across ALL browsers" - implementing a small unit test that verifies the implementation of 64bit precision floating point is entirely possible, and something I have seen implemented in the past for other languages.

Comment: @leebriggs, think about it to verify what your asking with 100% certainty you would have to test ***ALL BROWSERS*** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers), that gets a little better if you say "all current major browsers" and in that case, you'd have to take your effective set of browsers (IE7, IE8, IE9, IE9 Mobile, IE10, FF (last 2 versions, future 3 versions or so), chrome (last/future 5 versions or so), Opera?, Safari?, Safari Mobile?, Android Browser?, Chrome on android?, etc... [cont]

Comment: @leebriggs and then test them on each major stepping stone of each applicable architecture (different processors etc..) since math runs pretty close to the metal...and only then could you be 100% and only for a few months until a new browser/architecture comes out. As I said before ***IF*** you need 100% certainty there are better ways to do it then maintaining crazy browser compatibility list. **So, the short answer is no one will ever know.** The long answer I already gave you, and if I were you I would just forge ahead and stop worrying about something that you're not even sure is broken

Comment: @ckozi A unit test is something that could be part of the application/site. I'm obviously not looking for data on every browser that has ever existed, just any compatibility data as reasonably exists for many other questions.

Comment: @ckozi I did also just want to add that your advice is completely correct and appropriate as a way to avoid the problem. I'm afraid in my case I don't want to avoid it, I want to understand it.

Comment: I agree ckozl. Maybe what you should do @leebriggs if you want to understand it is examine the source code yourself. That is the best way to understand across browsers. If the source code is unavailable, contact the dev team and ask them and post what you find here. But if you just want to deploy a solution -- assume your results may contain some % of error, and deal with that the appropriate way for your code.

Comment: @cris It might well come to a few enquiries out to the browser teams, but starting here first. I'm starting with the presumption that some browsers would fail, but have little insight as to whether that would be 10%, 1%, 0.1% or 0.01%.

Comment: Cool. I get it. But you should still just make something, and be wide around the breaking points. 'Cheaper to try than to decide whether to try or not' :) Anyway, I wonder if the major browser is still IE? I just plan on supporting the latest crop of HTML5 compliant browsers and looking to the future. I like my js pure, light and my browsers standardised. I don't even like webkit extension -- traditional expectations of a single runtime environment die hard on the web.

Comment: There's no hurry, this isn't for a client or a project with a due date, and there has been some related coding. It came from a discussion in which the browser was seen as a heterogeneous platform for distributed processing. Perhaps Stackoverflow should have a bluesky tag to signify questions to think over in the bath.

Answer (score 5):

"I have a specific use in mind for a distributed web application, which would only work if I can rely on consistent results across all browsers."

Then the answer is no. You can not relay on a specification to tell you that a browser correctly handles floats. Chrome updates every 6 weeks, so even if you have the specifications Chrome could change there behavior in the next release.

You have to relay on feature testing that test your assumptions before each time before you calculations is run.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use a library for your calculations. For example [bignumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) has a good handling of floating point numbers. Here you should be save from environment changes because it uses it's own storage format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem since ages in computing.  And if you ask old programmers who matured from assembly language, they will tell you that you store important numbers in a different format and do manipulations on them in similar way too.

For example, a currency value can be saved as integer by multiplying the float value by 100 (to keep the 2 decimal places intact).  You can then safely do calculations and when you have to display the final result, divide there by 100.  Depending upon how many decimal places you have to keep secure and safe, you may have to select a different number other than 100.  Store things in a long value and be care-free about such problems ever.

This is what gives me satisfactory results across platforms so far.  I just keep myself away from the floating point arithmetic nuances this way

Comment: I'm really not sure how I could have made it any clearer in the question that this wasn't a suitable answer.  I went searching for an old programmer who matured from assembly language and found one in the mirror.